# Printing in the console objects of an array

Tags: javascript

Hi I have been trying to learn Javascript using codeacademy.com and I have reached an exercise that doesn't seem to make any sense when why the exercise I have written.This is my code:

```
 (function(){
    var bob = {
        firstName: "Bob",
        lastName: "Jones",

        phoneNumber: "(650) 777 - 7777",
        email: "bob.jones@example.com"
    };

    var mary = {
        firstName: "Mary",
        lastName: "Johnson",

        phoneNumber: "(650) 888 - 8888",
        email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
    };

    var contacts = [bob, mary];

    var printPerson = function(person){
        console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
    }

    var list = function(){
        var i = contacts.length;
        for(var j= 0; j < i ; j++){
            printPerson(contacts[i]);
        }
    };

        list();
})();
```

The problem is in the list function when I try to call the printPerson() function I get that person is undefined but if I write instead of the list() function this:

```
    printPerson(contacts[0]);
    printPerson(contacts[1]);
```

Everything works.What am I doing wrong in the list() function that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var list = function(){
    var i = contacts.length;
    for(var j= 0; j < i ; j++){
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
};
```

`i` here is a constant. If you replace it:

```
var list = function(){
    var i = contacts.length;
    for(var j= 0; j < contacts.length ; j++){
        printPerson(contacts[contacts.length]);
    }
};
```

For all arrays `arr`, `arr[arr.length]` will always be undefined. You probably want `contacts[j]`.

Comment: I must be blind or something can't belive I didn't see this mistake Thanks

Comment: @user1146440: it's easy to make that mistake when you name your length variable in the same way you name your indexing variables. call it `length` instead of `i`; you and everyone who reads your code will be saner for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var j= 0; j < i ; j++){
    printPerson(contacts[i]); // this should be contacts[j]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contacts.forEach(function(contact) {
    printPerson(contact);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888 - 8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};


 var contacts=[bob,mary];
 console.log(mary.phoneNumber);
```

Comment: Please add little of explanation to your answer for future visitors.